# Getting an error while trying to use converted IplImage objects from Mat objects in OpenCv

Tags: opencv

> IplImage *IplImg;
>
> Mat ImgMat(IplImg);
>
> imshow( "Mat", ImgMat);

In OpenCV, as above, I can convert an IplImage object to Mat object and use this new IplImage object with imshow function.

> Mat  ImgMat;
>
> IplImage IplImg(ImgMat); //no error
>
> cvNamedWindow("Ipl",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
>
> cvShowImage("Ipl",IplImg); // throws an error

But when it comes to converting a Mat object to IplImage object and using this new object with cvShowImage function, compiler gives an error : " No suitable conversion function from "IplImage" to "const CvArr *"

Can you please help me to figure out why this simple operation doesn't work with cvShowImage ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cvShowImage` expects a pointer to an IplImage

```
cvShowImage("Ipl",&IplImg); // should not throw
```